# How to get maximum value of each day in month using django queryset

Tags: django, django-models

Let's assume I have `Model`, Products and I have 100k records. Now I want to pass month `2022-01-01` and get `maximum` price of each day of the passed month.

**Product Model**

```
id     price     date
1.     33.33     2022-01-01
2.     93.33     2022-01-01
3.     64.33     2022-01-02
4.     34.33     2022-01-02
.
.
.
101.   43.33     2022-01-29
102.   74.33     2022-01-30
103.   36.33     2022-01-30
```

**Expecting Result**

```
93.33
64.33
.
.
.
43.33
74.33
```

Sorry I can't explain in more better way.

***Note***
I just want queryset. Kindly try avoid loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the objects and annotate a maximum per day with the following query:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Product.objects.filter(
    valuta_date__gte="startdate", valuta_date__lt="enddate"
).values("date").order_by("date").annotate(Max("price"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Product.objects.filter(
    my_date__year="2022", my_date__month="01"
).values('my_date').annotate(
  max_price=Max("price")
).order_by()
```

But I would suggest executing raw queries when dealing with large dataset as they work faster like this:

```
max_product_query = """
    SELECT id, MAX(price), my_date FROM your_app_product 
    WHERE strftime("%Y-%m", my_date) = '{0}' GROUP BY my_date;
""".format(year_month)

products = Product.objects.raw(max_product_query)
for product in products:
    # do something with the product
```

the above query is for sqlite for mysql and postgres use below:

```
max_product_query = """
    SELECT id, MAX(price), my_date FROM your_app_product 
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM my_date) = '{0}' GROUP BY my_date';
""".format(year_month)
```